# Is there a formula without if/else/switch/? etc that could replace the solution[,] matrix

Tags: c#, math

Is there a formula without if/else/switch/? etc that could replace the solution[,]  matrix and what are the implications or differences on performance/efficiency for that?

```
     class Program
{
    private static Random r = new Random();
    // names of the "moves"
    private static string[] rps = { "PAPER", "ROCK", "SCISSORS"};
    // result feedback string to be formatted
    private static string[] feedback = { "{1} Beats {0}, You Loose!","{0} Equals {1}, Draw!",  "{0} Beats {1}, You Win!" };
    // solution matrix ( 0 = loose ; 1 = draw ; 2 = win  // array1: for paper; array2: for rock; array3: for scissors; )
    private static int[,] solution = {{1, 2, 0},{0, 1, 2},{2, 0, 1}};

    /// <summary>
    /// Rock Paper scissors solution w/o calculation or if/case/else/
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">dummy.</param>
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            // simulate the players move
            int player = r.Next(3);

            // simulate the computers move
            int computer = r.Next(3);

            // retrieve the result from the matrix
            int result = solution[player, computer];

            //write the result of the match
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("you : {0} vs {1} : computer", rps[player], rps[computer]));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format(feedback[result], rps[player], rps[computer]));

    }
}
```

Comment: I was almost going to applaud the use of a `static` instance of `Random`, but the constructor use there is weird. What do people have against the parameterless constructor?

Comment: you mean like this? (changed the random constructor to parameterless)

Comment: Yep, that's what happens anyway, roughly at least. It uses `Environment.TickCount`. If you had an actual reason to use only millisecond precision there it might have been fine but I'd guess that doesn't apply to a whole lot of cases.

Comment: I know you are right. Thanks. This is a typical thing that I very rarely use, and when I use it, indeed overuse it inefficiently ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a quite simple formula:

```
player computer  solution  (c+4-p)%3
  0       0         1          1
  0       1         2          2
  0       2         0          0
  1       0         0          0
  1       1         1          1
  1       2         2          2
  2       0         2          2
  2       1         0          0
  2       2         1          1
```

So you can use:

```
int result = (computer + 4 - player) % 3;
```

Accessing the array and calculating the value would take rougly the same time. However, the difference in performance in this application is negligible. Just writing the result to the console takes a lot longer than either using the array or calculating the value. Of course, by calculating the value you don't need the array, but as it's so small that doesn't make much of a difference.

Consider also the readability of the solution. The formula has no logical connection to what you use it for, it's just a means to get to a specific result, so you would need a large comment that explains what it accomplishes...

#### Edit:

If you want focus on readability, you could put the logic in a separate class:

```
public class Play {

  public enum Value { Paper = 0, Rock = 1, Scissors = 2 }

  private Value _value;

  public Play(Random rnd) {
    _value = (Value)rnd.Next(3);
  }

  public bool SameAs(Play other) {
    return _value == other._value;
  }

  public bool Beats(Play other) {
    return
      (_value == Value.Paper && other._value == Value.Rock) ||
      (_value == Value.Rock && other._value == Value.Scissors) ||
      (_value == Value.Scissors && other._value == Value.Paper);
  }

  public override string ToString() {
    switch (_value) {
      case Value.Paper: return "PAPER";
      case Value.Rock: return "ROCK";
      default: return "SCISSORS";
    }
  }

}
```

Now the logic gets clearer:

```
Random r = new Random();

Play player = new Play(r);
Play computer = new Play(r);

Console.WriteLine("you : {0} vs {1} : computer", player, computer);

string feedback;
if (player.SameAs(computer)) {
  feedback = "{0} Equals {1}, Draw!";
} else if (player.Beats(computer)) {
  feedback = "{0} Beats {1}, You Win!";
} else {
  feedback = "{1} Beats {0}, You Loose!";
}

Console.WriteLine(feedback, player, computer);
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response. 
A test did indeed show that the formula worked! 
Perhaps you can explain what the 4 does? 
I've tried the same with 1, 2 and 3 but never came to 4. Funny But Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne: The 4 acts just like 1, as modulo 3 is then used, but it makes `(player+4)` always be larger than `computer`, so there is no negative numbers to worry about.

Comment: Man...thanks for the great lesson! I love this kind of stuff!!

Comment: The problem with the readability is indeed an issue I was struggling with. One thing is that the Behaviour of the rps[] array is "linear" while the result approaches the rps[] with a more triangular or "ring" perspective. To clarify that in code is pretty hard. The short-notation makes it even harder I guess. Challenges ahead so to say.

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne: For readablily I think that an `if` statement would be the best choise. I added an example with a class that encapsualtes the logic, and uses an `enum` for the values, which make it pretty readable.

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne: Why not try to apply it to rock, paper, scissors, spock, lizard? :)

Comment: @guffa. Thanks for your reply....but...... The whole exercise for me was based on two things: 1.) Separation of data and behaviour and my eager to proof that an if/then statement is not necessary when dealing with values that are already "predetermined". In this case, we are able to oversee all results (there are only 9) and perhaps we want indeed scale the application to a larger one (like rock, paper, scissors, spock, lizard..all starwarsfigures..etc). In that case Enumerators and if/else would not be a good solution.But I agree in this case, your solution is more readable ;) Thanks anyway!

Comment: I mean: You are right, but there is too little space to explain all details of this small program ;)